# Will marry vs will get married

Tags: verbs, differences, future

I have seen both sentences below:

> I will get married.
>
> I will marry.

So what is the difference? Which one is recommended? Is there any difference in meaning or just grammar?

Comment: @FumbleFingers neither question nor answer in that post relating to mine, i don't know why you are saying it is a duplicate.

Comment: If you search for the word "inchoative" in John Lawler's answer in the question to which @FumbleFingers is referring you, you will see the usage that "get married" represents ("become married" is equivalent to "get married").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning between the two forms, though the first one is much more common in speech. *I will get married* is the way that most people will say this most of the time.

*To marry* is much commoner when used transitively or reciprocally:

> I will marry John on Tuesday.
>
> John and Rachel will marry on Tuesday.

Answer (score -1):

i think "get married" is used to talk about status. And "marry" is simply an activity.

Comment: I see you've been downvoted, but I think there's some good truth to your answer. "Get [become] married" is a change in status, while the act of marrying is a finite act that creates a longer-term change (that same change in status).

Comment: @trang; this is a beginning to a good answer, I think; but it could use some references (e.g. can you point to a discussion of this in any works of grammar, or to actual usage in works of literature?) You might try checking for "marry him" or "marry her" versus "they get/got married" in Google Books, as a start.